# Widget Lifecycle?

Tags: mobile, blackberry, widget, windows-mobile, web-widget

Alot of phone OSes are starting to support W3C widgets, or something very similar.

I am still a little confused about what exactly widgets can do?

All the example widgets I have seen have just a 'index.html' page.  Are widgets allowed to have multiple pages they can navigate between?

Also do widgets have any mechanism to run in the background?

Any good online documentation about W3C widget lifecycle? or blackberry widgets?

Answer (score 1):

Widgets can do most things a native mobile application can do when augmented with support for the [W3C Device API specs](http://www.w3.org/2009/dap/) or the [WAC](http://www.wacapps.net/web/portal) profile that includes everything from accelerometers to roaming status.

Without these extensions, Widgets can still use local storage, preferences (a special type of HTML5 storage), app cache and other HTML5 goodies.

W3C Widgets can also package localized content, so one Widget can be deployed for all locales.

Also, there are other types of W3C Widgets implementations - for example desktop ([Opera](http://www.opera.com/)) and for web widgets ([Apache Wookie](http://incubator.apache.org/wookie/))

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not answer your question, but I can give you an example of an application that was developed for the mobile using W3C widgets. Here is a blog post that describes their use:

http://uxebu.com/blog/2010/02/15/eventninja-a-mobile-cross-platform-app/